# Samsung monitor bent forward, cannot flip the stand

Tags: desktop-computer

I have a Samsung monitor that's been bent forward since I bought it. For some reason, the way it sits on the stand, the screen is tilted towards me when I use it.

Model number is LS24D300HLR/ZA

I tried flipping the actual stand and the part that connects the stand to the rest of the monitor (top), but they all fit in only one way.

Anyone else faced this problem and know a solution or reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201510/20151030150055013/BN46-00382G-Eng.pdf), the screen should tilt from -1° (toward you) to 20° (away from you):
[image]
(Note that the upright part on the base is meant to be leaning towards you).

If the screen is leaning toward you at >1°, I would open a return/repair case with Samsung.

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response. Would <1 degree be noticeable in everyday use?

Comment: I couldn't tell a 1° difference from vertical, so no, it would not.

Comment: Then I'll open a case. Because even through prolonged use the tilt feels odd, although I'm getting used to it after a year.

Comment: Could there be a screw loose somewhere that causes this?  I know Samsung is famed for gluing everything rather than screw